# How a function will call with ng-repeat for all elements?

Tags: function, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to call a function with all elements of data-ng-repeat. How can i do this ? Experts please help me.

Code:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="message in global.user.sentMessages><div >{{message.created}}</div> </div>
```

function:

```
$scope.showDate= function(message){ var cast_time = new Date(message.created);                         
$scope.time=cast_time;}
```

I want to show organized date which is in showDate function. I want to show this date in message.created, but every time ng-repeat will call showDate function. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best way to do it seems to use a filter :

```
<div data-ng-repeat="message in global.user.sentMessages><div >{{message.created | showDate }}</div> </div>
```

And you can define your filter in application module:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).filter('showDate', function() {
    return function(myDate) {
      // return what you want to display
      var cast_time = new Date(message.created);
      return cast_time.getDate();
    };
});
```

You can use pre-defined angular filters:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).filter('showDate', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return function(myDate) {
        return $filter('date')(myDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
    };
}]);
```

Of course, you can use angular date filter directly without creating your own:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="message in global.user.sentMessages><div >{{message.created | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</div> </div>
```

See the documentation: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date